# Get base_path in twig file -- Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

How can i get the base path of drupal installation in twig file?

For example i need to get http://localhost/drupal/.

I have tried

```
{{ base_path }}
```

But it's returning empty.

```
{{ directory }}
```

This is returning the theme path. but i need the base path to complete the url. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ditto P S To get base path on twig you declare a variable in .theme file inside a preprocess

[image]

andthen simply use 'base_path_success' variable in twig as

```
{{ base_path_success }}
```

You can declare variable inside any of the preprocess like

```
function ttnd_preprocess_node(&$variables) {}
```

OR

```
function ttnd_preprocess_block(&$variables) {}
```

Here **ttnd** is themename.

For more information you can use the below link

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205289/base-path-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hostname, "localhost/drupal/", directly from the [`getHost()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetHost/8.2.x) request:

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
```

In some cases you might want to get the schema as well, fx `http://localhost/drupal/`:

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Source : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202811/